# MySql Update Query using nested Query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I want to update only the last row from the table logs.. which is arranged in ascending order by ID field.. following query gives the error

`update Inventory.logs as a set a.Session=90 where a.ID=(select max(ID) from Inventory.logs)`

gives error

```
you cant specify target table a for update in From Clause
```

Comment: Tables have no order except for that expressly defined in an ORDER BY clause... which, in its own way, is a clue.

Comment: What is the Solution?

Comment: Id field is auto inc. so max(ID) will automatically select last row

Comment: Max is not necessary for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code
i hope this is hepful

```
update Inventory.logs set Session=90 order by id desc limit 1
```